# AngularJs search

Tags: angularjs

How to apply search filter for the columns. Kindly help.

Comment: Provide the controller code

Comment: what searchValue mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ng-class directive to conditionally add css classes based on conditions. I think you want to place two columns side-by-side with some spacing and you don't need to have a new row for each two entries.

Then you could go with this version of ng-repeat together with ng-class:

```
<div class="row">
  <div ng-repeat = "person in persons | filter : searchValue"
       class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-4" 
       ng-class = "{'col-sm-offset-1': $index%2==0, 'col-sm-offset-2': $index%2==1}">
   {{person.name}}
</div>
```

Using a single row is enough because every two entries use more than 8 cols, such that after every two entries, a new "virtual row" is started.

See a working sample in this [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/gocuna/5/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

In the controller re-arrange your product to be tuples, ex:

`$scope.persons = [{foo},{bar},...]`

to:

`$scope.persons = [[{foo}, {bar}],[...],...]`

that way you can bind like this:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="person in persons | filter : searchValue" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">{{person[0].name}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">{{person[1].name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

p.d.: you can rearrange quite easily with a simple map function.